# When using equations in Pages, how can I make the square roots less "tall"?

Tags: pages, text, latex

I'm writing in Pages and have embedded or in-line equations. At some point Pages is not the tool and I'll have to learn how to use TeX or LaTeX perhaps, but for right now:

1. will the square root always be bigger when things inside have a descending "j"?
2. is there any way I can keep a, b, i, j, k, l about the same size but make the superscripts and square roots smaller so they don't make the parentheses look ineffective?

Maybe my eyes are tricking me or maybe I'm just used to MathJax in Stack Exchange, but the square roots just look better behaved than they do in Pages. Are there some other things I can adjust to reduce vertical extent without making the characters smaller?

Pages:

[image: Pages]

MathJax in Stack Exchange:

[image: MathJax in Stack Exchange]

```
Use $a \sqrt{i^2+j^2}$ (or $b \sqrt{k^2+l^2}$ on Tuesdays) and you're done.
```